# DST start and end date

Tags: oracle

Just wondering in Oracle 11g if there is an easy way I can find out the dst start and end date by passing any timezone and year please?

I've read through this post [In Oracle, how can I detect the date on which daylight savings time begins / ends?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/in-oracle-how-can-i-detect-the-date-on-which-daylight-savings-time-begins-end) but it doesn't give me what I need. I want to get the dst start/end date for any given timezon.

Many thanks

Comment: This has already been answered - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/in-oracle-how-can-i-detect-the-date-on-which-daylight-savings-time-begins-end

Comment: I've done my research and read through the above post before I asked the question. I want to get the dst start for any given timezone, not just US.